# toString() affecting original object type?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm not quite sure if this is a Java question, or a VS Code question:

I have a JSONObject using org.json, and I'm outputting it to string:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
 System.out.print(obj.toString());
```

at this point, when using the "intellisense" for VSCode, if I use obj, I get the appropriate intellisense options:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
System.out.print(obj.toString());
int len  = obj.length();
```

[image]

However, when I attempt to iterate over it using a for loop, when I'm getting the length of the object, the intellisense never shows, and I get an error that
"obj cannot be resolved to a type".

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
System.out.print(obj.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < obj.; i++) {
```

[image]

Interestingly, if I do something else with the object before using it within the for loop, or comment out `System.out.print(obj.toString());` , the intellisense works as expected.

[image]
[image]

At this point, I don't know if this is something to do with the print and toString() methods somehow affecting the original `obj` object? Or if it's some bug or limitation in VSCode.

Comment: 100% a bug or limitation in VSCode. The actual compiler is authoritative. Your tooltips are not.

Comment: My advice is don't use VSCode as your java IDE; use IntelliJ.

Comment: I have reported this on GitHub and got a response, it should be fixed soon.   Here is the [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2966#) so you can check it out anytime.

Comment: Thanks @JialeDu! I hadn't had a chance to create the issue, so I'm glad it got into the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

The problem will soon be fixed.

Steps to quickly verify the fix:

- download [com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core-0.7.0-fix.zip](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/files/10895163/com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core-0.7.0-fix.zip)
- **rename** it to `com.microsoft.jdtls.intellicode.core-0.7.0-fix.jar`. (do not extract)
- copy it into folder `~/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode-1.2.30/dist/`
- open file `~/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode-1.2.30/package.json`, search for "core-0.7.0.jar", change it to "core-0.7.0-fix.jar" accordingly, save the file.
- reload/re-open your Java project, try the code comletion.

*Originally posted by @Eskibear in https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2966#issuecomment-1455553830*